# Mysql Select two column in different table

Tags: php, mysql

as below I select two different column(count_group and group_total) with same table and condition.
I feel that this method makes the page slow. Any suggestion?

```
$sql3 = "SELECT SUM(mr.payment_amount) as total ,
COUNT(mr.order_id) as count_personal , 

(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT mr.group_order_id) 
FROM event_mgmt_registration mr 
WHERE mr.event_nid = ".$nid." 
AND mr.status='completed' 
AND DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`datestamp`), '%Y-%m-%d') <= '".$Sum['latest_date']."' 
AND mr.group_order_id != '' ) as count_group ,

(SELECT SUM(mr.payment_amount) 
FROM event_mgmt_registration mr 
WHERE mr.event_nid = ".$nid." 
AND mr.status='completed' 
AND DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`datestamp`), '%Y-%m-%d') <= '".$Sum['latest_date']."' 
AND mr.group_order_id != '' ) as group_total 

FROM event_mgmt_registration mr 
WHERE mr.event_nid =".$nid." 
AND mr.status='completed'  
AND DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`datestamp`), '%Y-%m-%d') <= '".$Sum['latest_date']."' 
AND mr.order_id !=''";
```

Comment: what does `explain` shows for your query ?

Comment: Well, do you just FEEL that it makes your page slow, or does it actually page it slow? Measure each query by itself and provide information about running times, use EXPLAIN to get proper information about how MySQL runs your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For better performance your better do a UNION to get the three results as a line each:

```
SELECT 
SUM(mr.payment_amount) as total ,
COUNT(mr.order_id) as count_personal
FROM event_mgmt_registration mr 
WHERE mr.event_nid =".$nid." 
AND mr.status='completed'  
AND DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`datestamp`), '%Y-%m-%d') <= '".$molpaySum['latest_date']."' 
AND mr.order_id !=''

UNION ALL

(SELECT NULL, COUNT(DISTINCT mr.group_order_id)
FROM event_mgmt_registration mr 
WHERE mr.event_nid = ".$nid." 
AND mr.status='completed' 
AND DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`datestamp`), '%Y-%m-%d') <= '".$molpaySum['latest_date']."' 
AND mr.group_order_id != '' )

UNION ALL

(SELECT NULL, SUM(mr.payment_amount)
FROM event_mgmt_registration mr 
WHERE mr.event_nid = ".$nid." 
AND mr.status='completed' 
AND DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`datestamp`), '%Y-%m-%d') <= '".$Sum['latest_date']."' 
AND mr.group_order_id != '' )
```

Comment: $query3 = db_query($sql3);
$Sum= $query3->fetchAssoc();$result = $howeiSum['count_group'] ; ERROR:Undefined index: count_group , sorry is the union problem that cannot defined the count_group and group_total? total and count_personal is fine

Comment: Try my Updated answer.

Comment: i realize that union is only use the first select column name, so the group_order_id and payment_amount is under total and count_personal... Thanks for the union method

Comment: btw, is union run faster than the sql I posted?

Answer (score 0):

Why you need a query for every param? You can make it with one query i think

try this

```
$sql3 = "
    SELECT 
        SUM(mr.payment_amount) as total ,
        COUNT(mr.order_id) as count_personal , 
        COUNT(DISTINCT mr.group_order_id) as count_group,
        SUM(mr.payment_amount) as group_total

    FROM event_mgmt_registration mr 

    WHERE 
        mr.event_nid =".$nid." AND 
        mr.status='completed'  AND 
        DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`datestamp`), '%Y-%m-%d') <= 
            '".$molpaySum['latest_date']."' AND 
        mr.order_id !=''
";
```

Note that in group_total you use `$Sum['latest_date']` but not `$molpaySum['latest_date']`. If its not a misprint, you should retain this query, like this:

```
    $sql3 = "
    SELECT 
        SUM(mr.payment_amount) as total ,
        COUNT(mr.order_id) as count_personal , 
        COUNT(DISTINCT mr.group_order_id) as count_group,
        (SELECT SUM(mr.payment_amount) 
         FROM event_mgmt_registration mr 
         WHERE mr.event_nid = ".$nid." 
             AND mr.status='completed' 
             AND DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`datestamp`), '%Y-%m-%d') <=
                 '".$Sum['latest_date']."' 
             AND mr.group_order_id != '' 
        ) as group_total 

    FROM event_mgmt_registration mr 

    WHERE 
        mr.event_nid =".$nid." AND 
        mr.status='completed'  AND 
        DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`datestamp`), '%Y-%m-%d') <= 
            '".$molpaySum['latest_date']."' AND 
        mr.order_id !=''
";
```